# Runge Kutta Method for in $1+1$ dimension

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

Given a partial differential equation

$\partial_t u(t,x) = F(t,x,u,u')$

Suppose I know the functions $u(t_0,x)$ and $u'(t_0,x)$ at some point $t_0$ for all $x$. In order to obtain the function $u$ at the next time step $t_0 + \Delta t$, I may use the Runge Kutta method. However, within Runge Kutta method, expressions of the form $F(t_0 + \Delta t, x, u + \Delta t \cdot g, ...)$ must be calculated. My question now is, if this "shift" of the function $u$ is carried out before differentiating with respect to $x$ or after.

In detail, does the expression look like this

$F\Big( t_0 + \Delta t, x, u + \Delta t \cdot g, \partial_x u + \Delta t \cdot g \Big)$

or like this

$F\Big( t_0 + \Delta t, x, u + \Delta t \cdot g, \partial_x (u + \Delta t \cdot g) \Big) = F\Big(t_0 + \Delta t, x, u + \Delta t \cdot g, \partial_x u \Big)$

Comment: It makes no sense to add $\Delta t g$ to $\partial_x u$, they don't even have the same dimensions. So if it is either of these, it must be the second one (except your simplification on the RHS of the second equation is wrong).

Comment: With more clarity: RK in the PDE context is really an ODE time stepping method. This means that your problem should really already be an ODE, which means that the spatial derivative(s) need to be folded into the state. In other words, you should really be thinking of $(u,u')$ as one 2N dimensional vector at each time step, so the spatial derivatives are taken first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am, however, not quite comfortable with your last sentence. If it is the second possibility (where the RHS is wrong as you stated), then the spatial derivatives are not taken first, are they? The addition of $\Delta t \cdot g$ is taken first -- or am I misunderstanding your statement?

Am I right in assuming, that the RHS is wrong because $g \equiv g(x)$?

Comment: g depends on x, so it has its own spatial derivative. So what gets added to $u_x$ is $\Delta t g_x$.

Comment: Ah yes understood. If you want to write your answer as an „answer“, I would and could gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RK is really an ODE time stepping method, so to use it to solve a dynamic PDE, you should first convert to an ODE by spatial discretization. So for example in 1 space dimension you might do finite differences as $u(t,x) = u^j_i$ with $t=j\Delta t,x=i\Delta x$ and $u_x(t,x) \approx (\partial_x u)^j_i := \frac{u^j_{i+1}-u^j_{i-1}}{2\Delta x}$ (centered space differences). Then far enough away from the boundary you can take $F(t,x,u,u') \approx F^j_i:=F(j\Delta t,i\Delta x,u^j_i,(\partial_x u)^j_i)$. Then when you adjust $u$ you must also adjust the spatial derivative accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To best understand how to apply RK4 to multiple values, it is best to view it in ***vector*** form.

The time evolution of the ODE is governed by the temporal derivative of the state vector $\boldsymbol{Y}$

$$ \boldsymbol{\dot{Y}} = {\rm f}( t,\, \boldsymbol{Y} ) $$

where $\boldsymbol{Y} = \pmatrix{y_1 \\ y_2 \\  \vdots }$ is the state vector containing all your degrees of freedom.

In your case, **you have spatial derivatives $y'_i$ that need to be expressed in terms of your state variables inside the ${\rm f}(t,\boldsymbol{Y})$ function**.

A naive implementation would be

$$ \boldsymbol{Y}'=\frac{1}{\Delta x}\begin{bmatrix} & \frac{1}{2}\\
\text{-}\frac{1}{2} &  & \frac{1}{2}\\
 & \text{-}\frac{1}{2} &  & \ddots\\
 &  & \ddots &  & \ddots\\
 &  &  & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{Y} $$

now you can construct $\boldsymbol{\dot{Y}}$ since you have $t$,$\boldsymbol{Y}$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}'$

Finally on each sub-step you get to re-evaluate ${\rm f}()$ which means you need to re-evaluate the above

$$\begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{K}_{0} & ={\rm f}(t,\boldsymbol{Y})\\
\boldsymbol{K}_{1} & ={\rm f}(t+\Delta t/2,\boldsymbol{Y}+\Delta t/2\,\boldsymbol{K}_{0})\\
\boldsymbol{K}_{2} & ={\rm f}(t+\Delta t/2,\boldsymbol{Y}+\Delta t/2\,\boldsymbol{K}_{1})\\
\boldsymbol{K}_{3} & ={\rm f}(t+\Delta t,\boldsymbol{Y}+\Delta t\,\boldsymbol{K}_{2})
\end{aligned}$$

and the change in state variables

$$\Delta\boldsymbol{Y}=\frac{\Delta t}{6}\left(\boldsymbol{K}_{0}+2\boldsymbol{K}_{1}+2\boldsymbol{K}_{2}+\boldsymbol{K}_{3}\right)$$